# how to make others use my .py files to test it?

Tags: python, testing, assembly, cmd

I have developed a simple MIPS instruction set assembler that takes instruction from the user & output the machine code in text file using python 2.7. I want to make this program executable out of IDE; I mean I want to deliver this project to someone that doesn't have python installed on his computer. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can compile a python script into a .exe in windows using Pyinstaller. Read tutorial here. (http://www.pyinstaller.org/)